# Ajax success: function (res) { not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, phpmailer

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mailer.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(res) {
    alert(res);
    window.location.href = 'http://bharatikafest.petra.ac.id/lalala2022lalala/member/pendaftaran/notif.php';
  }
});
```

I want to alert res after it's successful and it works at first but suddenly it didn't work. So I tried to make a new page just for notification, and redirect it there after it's successful. But now, both didn't work. Any idea how to make any of those two ways works?

Comment: Does the HTTP request succeed at all? Does it even finish?

Comment: it suceed, the data successfully sent to the database and mailer also works, just the success function didn't work

Comment: "*the data successfully sent to the database and mailer also works,*" that means that the HTTP call *reaches the destination*. Not that it gets a response. Check the Network tab in the browser tools and see the status of the call.

Comment: All status are 200

Comment: *always* add an `error:function...` parameter/callback - it will tell you what the error is *after* jquery receives the response and before jquery returns it to your code.  You don't specify a `dataType:` so jquery will base it on the MIME type - if your mime type doesn't match the data, jquery won't be able to parse it.   Add `dataType:'text'` to your jquery call to see what you're getting (along with the `error:` and checking the network tab)

Comment: Strangely enough, if you have no code to handle errors, your errors are not going to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

with respect to error(), from https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/:

Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Instead of success you could try to use the done() method.

Comment: You're confusing `success:` with `.success()`

Comment: Youre right. In this case ajax.error with  jqXHR.error().

Comment: No, I mean you're confusing the parameter `success:` and `error:` with the jqXHR methods `.success()` and `.error()`.   Not success/error

Comment: The deprecated *methods* are for code like `$.ajax({ url: "whatever"}).success(handleSuccess)` not for `$.ajax({ url: "whatever", success: handleSuccess})` But you can still use the newer methods like `$.ajax({ url: "whatever"}).done(handleSuccess)`